# ModX Evo: Cannot create images folder

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I have just installed Evo 1.0.15 but get the following error when I try to add an image or file link in TinyMCE:

`Cannot create images folder`

This occurs when the file browser window opens.

I have checked and there is an images folder both in my assets and root directories. Both have open permissions (777).

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was because the images directory path was incorrect in the Configurations list